# Bind ContextMenu Command to parents viewmodel RelayCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, parent

I have a `TvShowsViewModel` (1) that contains an `ObservableCollection` of `TvShowViewModel`s (2). A `TvShowViewModel` contains an `ObservableCollection` of `SeasonViewModel`s (3).

I have a `TreeView`, which has the `TvShowsViewModel` (1) as `DataContext`. The `ItemSource` of that `TreeView` binds to the `ObservableCollection` of `TvShowViewModels` (2).

The `TreeView` specifies a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, which binds to the `ObservableCollection` of `SeasonViewModels` (3).

The `HierarchicalDataTemplate` contains a `ContextMenu`.

Now, the `ContextMenu` contains a `Command` which I want to bind to a `RelayCommand` in the `TvShowsViewModel` (1).

I tried all kinds of `RelativeSource` bindings, but nothing that leads to the solution. How should I specify the binding?

TvShowsViewModel (1)

```
public class TvShowsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand ExcludeSeasonCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<TvShowViewModel> TvShows { get; private set; }

    public TvShowsViewModel(ITvShowsLibrary tvShowsLibrary)
    {
        TvShows = new ObservableCollection<TvShowViewModel>();

        ExcludeSeasonCommand = new RelayCommand(ExcludeSeasonCommandOnExecute, ExcludeSeasonCommandOnCanExecute);

    // Left out irrelevant code
    }
}
```

TvShowViewModel (2)

```
public class TvShowViewModel : ViewModelBase, IFolderOnDisk
{
    public ObservableCollection<SeasonViewModel> Seasons
    {
        get { return _seasons; }
    }

    // Left out irrelevant code
}
```

SeasonViewModel (3)

```
public class SeasonViewModel : ViewModelBase, IFolderOnDisk
{
    // Left out irrelevant code
}
```

The stripped user control (TreeView)

```
<!-- Again, left out a lot of irrelevant parts -->
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TvShows}">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="tvShows:TvShowViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem
                                    Header="Exclude season"
                     <!-- This is where I need your help, how should I configure the binding? -->
                                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ExcludeSeasonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

The binding, which I can't figure out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, after many many many google searches I ran into the solution

```
<MenuItem
    Header="Exclude season"
    Command="{Binding DataContext.ExcludeSeasonCommand, Source={x:Reference _tvShowsTreeView}}" />
```

Because the HierarchicalDataTemplate does not appear in the visual tree, there is not "relative" source...

I hope this helps somebody else who's pulling his/her hair out...

Comment: Thanks! Saved some of my hair! Note you need to give the TreeView a Name to use as the x:Reference.